# Can I receive intents as long as my activity is running?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

I have an `Activity` which needs to receive broadcast intents as long as it is running. There is a problem with this when you read the Android developer documentation:

I must unregister the receiver before the activity is closed. The recommended way is to register in `onResume` and unregister in `onPause`. However, this will not satisfy my requirements since I must detect the `Intent` that is sent from another application in my `Activity` (but only as long as I'm in the background, if my `Activity` is closed for whatever reason, I don't care about the `Intent`).

So, my question is:
I don't want my `Activity` to be created when the intent is received, so I don't want to add it to my AndroidManifest. But as long as my `Activity` is alive (in front or in back) I need to receive every `Intent` of a specific kind sent.
How do accomplish this?

Comment: "Once onReceive has been called, the system regards it as obsolete." - Where does the documentation say that?

Comment: define: *is alive(paused or not)* in terms of activity's  lifecycle ...

Comment: @Smartphone Developer: What part of the question is confusing you?

Comment: @Knossos I was thinking about the passage in Broadcast Receiver Lifecycle (Android SDK Documentation): "A BroadcastReceiver object is only valid for the duration of the call to onReceive(Context, Intent). Once your code returns from this function, the system considers the object to be finished and no longer active."
But I see now that I read it again that I might have misunderstood the point of the text. It may just refer to the thread/process running the receiver, not the receiver itself.

Comment: The same way I have to read your question tries (3 times), i was about to ask for this " is alive(paused or not) " but it was being asked that's y i removed my query

Comment: @Selvin: I mean that the Activity exists and has not been destroyed by the system. It is also either in front or in the back (not destroyed or stopped).

Comment: @TheScienceBoy That is technically correct. The BroadcastReceiver object itself, does not run the entire time. The object is only created as a result of Android processing an Intent Action, if your BroadcastReceiver acts on the Action.

Comment: I don't see the point of this ... use onStart/onStop or onResume/onPause ... reciving broadcast in other cases should not interest activity(it make more sens to use service and directly start/stop it) ... what you are wana do if you get the broadcast in your hypothetical state(still don't get it, there is no such state in activity lifecycle) ... onDestory is mostly usless event

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Register your `BroadcastReceiver` in your activity's `onCreate()` and unregister in `onDestroy()`. `onReceive()` will get called even if your Activity is paused and in the background. When your app is killed (or if your app quits), it will no longer get called.

Comment: This is the solution I'm currently employing. It has the downside that `onDestroy` is not guaranteed to be called if my process is killed by the system. If that happens the Broadcast Receiver would leak.
This would be extra unfortunate during a situation with high memory pressure.

Comment: No. If your process is killed, there is no leak. Killing a process reclaims all of its memory. You don't have to worry about that.

Comment: Is there no risk that the `BroadcastReceiver`, since it is registered with the Android System survives such a process killing? Or at least that there might be resources in the Android System that are not released with the process?

Comment: No, there is no risk. This is no problem at all. You register a chunk of code. When that chunk of code is gone, it is gone.

Answer (score 0):

1. Add a BroadcastReceiver to your AndroidManifest.
2. Add a static state holder in your Activity.

   public static AtomicBoolean sActivityDestroyed = new AtomicBoolean(false);

Set it to false in your Activity onResume and true in your onDestroy.

3. In your BroadcastReceiver, check whether the Activity state is false. If it is, then do your thing.

Comment: and of course you will end *Jackin' it in San Diego* as `onDestroy` may not be called and `sActivityDestroyed` can still be true ...

Comment: How so? The state will be true only if the Activity is destroyed. The point is that he wants to act on a Broadcast when the Activity is "alive". I interpret that as "not destroyed".

Comment: Creating a broadcast receiver for an activity that is not listening seems suboptimal to me. I would like a solution that does not require the Broadcast Receiver to exist when the Activity does not.

Comment: Your BroadcastReceiver is not "running" when your Activity isn't. It is simply there, if Android decides to search for Receivers that act on a certain action.

Comment: It would be running whenever the `Intent` was sent, whether my `Activity` exists or not. This is what I don't like. But I do see the merits of your answer. It is a solution that works.